# image not displayed when data place into UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiimage, nsstring, jpeg

We have NSString like this

```
 NSString *html=@"<html><body><img src='watchs.jpg' height='60%' width='40%'></body></html>";
```

Watchs.jpg We place into Local File.We tried to displayed webView on image like this

```
[BigImageShow loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

But image not showing .Please guide to us

Comment: try Using .png image instead of .jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not told the Web view where to look for the image. To solve this, set the baseURL to the local file directory:

> NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:....];

Pass this url as the argument to `loadHTMLString`:

> [BigImageShow loadHTMLString:html baseURL:url];

Comment: thanks for reply We don't have path.We have only NSString.In this case Please guide to us

Comment: Where do you put the file watchs.jpg? That is the path you need.

Comment: we tried as you said.We already add image to my project it's path like this 
<img src='Promotion/Pro_Ext/watchs.jpg'.We tried like this but we don't have luck Please guide to us